# Converting result of Math.sin(x) into a result for degrees in java

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I would like to convert the `Math.sin(x)`, where `x` in radians to a result which will give me as `x` in degrees not radians.

I have used the normal method and java built in method of conversion between degrees and radians,  but any argument I pass to the `Math.sin()` method is being treated as radians, thereby causing my conversion to be a futile effort.

I want the output of a sin Input to be given as if the input is treated in degrees not radians like the `Math.sin()` method does.

Comment: Yes, you convert your degrees value into a radians value first. Search for "convert degrees to radians" - or better, use `Math.toRadians`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Java's `Math` library gives you methods to convert between degrees and radians: [toRadians](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)) and [toDegrees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double)):

```
public class examples
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println( Math.toRadians( 180 ) ) ;
         System.out.println( Math.toDegrees( Math.PI ) ) ;
    }
}
```

If your input is in degrees, you need to convert the number going in to `sin` to radians:

```
double angle = 90 ;
double result  = Math.sin( Math.toRadians( angle ) ) ;
System.out.println( result ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks,I av tried all this earlier on before asking the question,then I relized that whatever argument I pass to the Math.sin() method will be treated has a radian value,making it hard for me to give the result of the Sin value of a number,with the number being in degrees.Please How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

if your radian value is a, then multiply the radian value with (22/7)/180.

The code would be like this for the above situation:-

```
double rad = 45            // value in radians.
double deg ;
deg = rad * Math.PI/180;   // value of rad in degrees.
```

Comment: just to make sure you are, and anyone reading this is, aware: 22/7 is only **approximately** pi

Answer (score 0):

You can convert radians to degrees like this:

```
double rad = 3.14159;
double deg = rad*180/Math.PI;
```

And the reverse to convert degrees to radians (multiply by pi/180). You can't change the "input method" for Math.sin (**you can't tell the function to use degrees instead of radians**), you can only change what you pass it as a parameter. If you want the rest of the program to work with degrees, you have to convert it to radians especially for Math.sin(). In other words, multiply the degrees value by pi and divide by 180. To use this with Math.sin(), just convert it like so:

```
double angle = 90;    //90 degrees
double result = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180);
```

Just using the conversion by itself doesn't change anything, you have to pass the converted value to the sin function.

Comment: Perhaps you missed that `3.14159` was never used as a value of pi, but merely an angle in radians to be converted to degrees. `Math.PI` was used in all the places where the true value of pi was important.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print sin(90) degree value, you can use this code:

```
double value = 90.0;
double radians = Math.toRadians(value);

System.out.format("The sine of %.1f degrees is %.4f%n", value, Math.sin(radians));
```